# Дополнить справочник новыми данными из другой таблицы

Tags: sql

Есть два справочника с производителями товаров, в одном 5, во втором 6.
В первом справочнике использованы авто инкрементальные идентификаторы для столбца manufacturer_id.
Во втором есть только список производителей
Необходимо основной справочник дополнить новыми данными из вспомогательного

использовал запрос:

```
    insert into manufacturer
(manufacturer)
select manufacturer from invoice_order_raw_2
   group by manufacturer;

select row_number () over (order by manufacturer) manufacturer_id, manufacturer from manufacturer;
```

---

Но на выходе получаю список из 11 позиций с дублями по производителям

Comment: математически 5 + 6 = 11, что верно. Вы какой результат хотели увидеть при добавлении 6 строк к 5 строкам?

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035), пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: Если manufacturer уже есть в таблице, чего же его еще добавлять? Проверьте not in (select manufacturer from manufacturer)

Comment: В справочниках производители пересекаются. На выходе необходимо получить один справочник, в котором будут только уникальные производители из двух таблиц. Их всего 6